# UIButton should respond to drag event

Tags: objective-c, events, xcode5

I have four UIButtons in a UIView. I need those buttons should respond to drag, if I drag over them they should respond. My Aim is if user drag on UIView over those Buttons those buttons should disappear. How can i make it happen.

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "drag over a button". Is it a tap/click? Do you mean hover?

Comment: Like gesture the path of the gesture go over the button that button should disappear. What exactly i am trying to do is i will put some buttons in the shape of a letter if the user drag his finger over those buttons those buttons should disappear as his finger go over them. How can i do that?